# How to make a substring pyramid psuedocode with words on Python?

Tags: python

**How would you make this code on python?**

[HERE IS THE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYxo7.png)

so far i have used `mystr = "Hello"
for i in range(len(mystr)+1):
    print (mystr[:i])
for i in range(len(mystr)-1):
    print (mystr[:i])`
but i cant descend back, im not asking for an answer, i just need help. thank you!

Comment: I ask you the same question. What have you implemented so far and what is wrong with it?

Comment: It's a basic programming task for school. Attempt yourself, play with loops and strings.

Comment: i made the first part, but i don't know how to descend back

Comment: Your output example has "he" twice, was that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there

```
s = "hello"

out = ""
for letter in s:
    out += letter
    print(out)

for letter in out:
    out = out[:-1]
    print(out)
```

Output:

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```

Answer (score 0):

you may do like below:

```
string = "hello"
output = list()
for c in string:
    if len(output) > 0:
        output.append(output[-1] + c)
    else:
        output.append(c)

pyramid = output + list(reversed(output[:-1]))
print ' '.join(pyramid)
```

output:

```
h he hel hell hello hell hel he h
```

Comment: For an actual displayed pyramid, `' '.join` should be `'\n'.join`